# PHP MYSQL OPTIONAL MULTIPLE IMAGE UPLOAD

Tags: php, image, upload

I have a html form with image (multiple images) upload which is optional

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>Name:</label><input type="text" name="name"/></br>
<label>Brief:</label><input type="text" name="brf"/></br>
<label>Result:</label><input type="text" name="res"/></br>
<label>Photographs:</label><input type="file" name="file[]" accept="image" multiple="multiple" /></br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add"/></br>
</form>
```

I have an image upload function which is working fine with images and fails without images. I tried to split this function like

```
if (empty($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'])) {
//my text only function
}
else {
//my with images function
}
```

but no matter what I do, this does not call `texonly()` function

I've tried

```
if (empty($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i]))

if (($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] ==""))

if (empty($_FILES['files'.$i]['tmp_name']))

if (empty($_FILES['files']['size']))

if (($_FILES['files']['size'] == 0))
equels
not equels
is_uploaded_file
..etc..etc
```

but nothing works for me...Any help would be life saving

`print_r($_FILES)` output

with file

```
   Array ( [files] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => Penguins.jpg ) [type] => Array ( [0] => image/jpeg ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => C:\wamp\tmp\php94CF.tmp ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 777835 ) ) )
```

without file

```
Array ( [files] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => ) [type] => Array ( [0] => ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) ) )
```

Comment: First step: debug. Do a `print_r($_FILES)` and see what it outputs.

Comment: with files`Array ( [files] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => Penguins.jpg ) [type] => Array ( [0] => image/jpeg ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => C:\wamp\tmp\php94CF.tmp ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 777835 ) ) ) `

Comment: without file `Array ( [files] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => ) [type] => Array ( [0] => ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) ) ) `

Answer (score 0):

Your file tag name is `file`

```
<label>Photographs:</label><input type="file" name="file[]" accept="image" multiple="multiple" /></br>
```

so you check with `file` not `files`

```
if (empty($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
//my text only function
}
else {
//my with images function
}
```

Comment: I've tried that too. upload an image or not,  it adds a new entry in DB without image. anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

you use `['name']` instead of `['tmp_name']`,`tmp_name` is only recovered after the image has been uploaded

```
if (empty($_FILES['files']['name'])) {
//my text only function
}
else {
//my with images function
}
```